# <s:file> doesn't retain its value when validation failed in action using Struts 2

Tags: ajax, validation, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery

I have some fields in jsp including file field. When I submit my form, and then if validation failed for one fields, after setting it in `ActionErrors`, when response comes back to JSP, all fields retain their values **except File field**.

**My Code:**

```jsp
<s:form autocomplete="off" action="carrier-profile" id="id_form_carrier" namespace="/usermgmt"
                enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">

<s:text name="txt.carrier.url"></s:text><span class="astrcs">*</span></label> <span>
                            <s:textfield type="text" name="carrier.carrierUrl" class="form-control" maxlength="255" tabindex="12"></s:textfield>


<s:file name="carrier.file" class="upload-input" id="imgInp" accept="image/*" tabindex="12"></s:file>
<s:submit/>

</s:form>
```

**My Action Class:**

```java
public class CarrierProfileAction extends BaseSecureAction {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(CarrierProfileAction.class);

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7296331027656555878L;

    private static final String RESULT_CARRIER_SEARCH = "carrier-search";
    //  private static final String RESULT_LOGO_PREVIEW = "logo-preview";
    //  private static final String RESULT_LOGO_UPDATE = "logo-update";
    public static final String CARRIER_ID = "carrierId";
    public static final String CARRIER_ID_NBR = "carrierIdNbr";
    public static final String RECORD_MODE = "mode";

    private static final String IMAGE = "Image";

    private CarrierVO carrier = new CarrierVO();

    //  private File file;
    private Long carrierId;
    private Long carrierIdNbr;
    private Long selectedCarrier;
    private boolean imagePreviewToBeShown;
    private String mode;
    private byte[] imagePreview;

    private String userImageFileName = "";

    private boolean validImage;
    InputStream imageInputStream;


}
```

Above code, `carrier` object has all its and its fields getter setter. No issue in that.
all the other fields `name="carrier.xxx"` are retaining except file.

Comment: You can't do anything about it. The server can't prepopulate an input of type file, for security / privacy reasons. The only way would be to stay on the page and submit the form using AJAX.

Comment: ok. we can use AJAX. thankss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't retain a file field due browser restriction rules. But you can use Ajax via Struts2 jQuery plugin

```xml
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<html>
  <head>
    <sj:head/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <s:form autocomplete="off" action="carrier-profile" id="id_form_carrier" namespace="/usermgmt"
                enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">

      <s:text name="txt.carrier.url"></s:text><span class="astrcs">*</span></label> <span>
      <s:textfield type="text" name="carrier.carrierUrl" cssClass="form-control" maxlength="255" tabindex="12"></s:textfield>
    
      <s:file name="carrier.file" cssClass="upload-input" id="imgInp" accept="image/*" tabindex="12"></s:file>

      <sj:submit value="Submit" />
    </s:form>
  </body>
</html>
```